# how to get value from another table with join code igniter

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database, codeigniter

I have 2 tables that joined from 1 database, I need to get `"kategori"` column from `"kategori"` table joined with `"artikel"` table. I can't get the `"kategori"` colum and it said

**ERROR**

> undefined index:kategori

**CONTROLLER**

```
public function edit($id){
        $this->load->helper('form');
        $this->load->library('form_validation');

        $this->form_validation->set_rules('judul', 'judul', 'required');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('konten','konten','required');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('id_kategori','id_kategori','required');

        if($this->form_validation->run()===false){
            $data['artikel'] = $this->m_daftar->ambil($id);
            $this->load->view('v_daftar_edit',$data);
        }else{
            $this->m_daftar->update($id);
            redirect('/daftar','refresh');
        }
    }
```

**MODELS**

```
public function ambil($id = FALSE){
    if($id===FALSE){
        $this->db->select('*');
        $this->db->form('artikel');
        $this->db->join('kategori', 'kategori.id_kategori = artikel.id_kategori');

        $query = $this->db->get();
        return $query->result_array();
    }
    $query = $this->db->get_where('artikel',array('id'=>$id));
    return $query->row_array();
}
```

and this is my view, i need it to show the value when i'm editing a table

**VIEW**

```
<select name="id_kategori" id="id_kategori" class="form-control">
    <option selected><?php echo $artikel['kategori']; ?></option>

</select>
```

sorry for my bad english

Comment: shouldn't `$this->db->form('artikel');` be `$this->db->from('artikel');` ?

Comment: well, i realize that typo and fix it. but it doesnt change anything. i cant get the value from another column from "kategori" but i can get all the value from "artikel", and i keep get notice that another column from "kategori" doesnt exist

Comment: most likely your join is incorrect: try kategori.id_kategori = artikel.id or however else your tables are connected...

Answer (score 1):

Please try this I hope there is problem in your code.

```php
public function ambil($id = FALSE){
    
    $select = ($id === FALSE) ? "artikel.*, kategori.kategori AS kategori" : "*";
    $this->db->select($select);
    $this->db->form('artikel');

    if($id===FALSE){

        $this->db->join('kategori', 'artikel.id_kategori = kategori.id_kategori', 'left'); // You need to define which Join you are going to use like left, right, inner, outer

        return $this->db->get()->result_array();
    }
    
     return $this->db->get_where('artikel',array('id'=>$id))->row_array();
}
```

If this did not work call my attention let me check another way of solving this problem. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

**You need to define which Join you are going to use like left, right, inner, outer**

```
$this->db->join('kategori', 'kategori.id_kategori = artikel.id_kategori');

replace with 

$this->db->join('kategori', 'kategori.id_kategori = artikel.id_kategori','left');
```